# Hiding a Javascript Array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Right now I have a function that looks like this:

```
function hidearray() {
    $('#one, #two, #three').hide();
}
```

I'd like to put those IDs into 1 array, which would look like

```
var myArray['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

And then hide that array within my function hidearray().  I thought it would look like this, but I guess I'm on the wrong track (I also know I ignored the # in the statement below)

```
$(.each(myArray)).hide();
```

The solution is likely simple, so thank you to all that respond!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery selectors are just strings, so create a string by joining the array :

```
$('#' + myArray.join(', #')).hide();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3PX4P/)

Comment: +1 I think `.join` is the most straightforward way to approach this.

Comment: Thanks everybody for such a quick rush of comments!

This was the shortest solution.

Answer (score 3):

I’d use `getElementById`. Assuming support for `Array.map`:

```
var myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

$(myArray.map(document.getElementById, document)).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
     $(myArray[i]).hide();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray['one', 'two', 'three'];
$.each(myArray,function(i,v){
   $('#'+v).hide();
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/Utg7p/

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/pfVt5/)***

Use `each`, pass the array as the first parameter, and the second will be the callback to work with the current item

```
var arr = [];
arr.push("#one");
arr.push("#two");
arr.push("#three");
$.each(arr,function(){
 $(""+this).hide();
});
```

Comment: @minitech - It's really important to make sure the strings are strings.

Comment: @minitech - Because it isn't treated like a string otherwise.

Comment: @TravisJ: Oh, right. jQuery and its silly string-objects-aren’t-strings thing.

Comment: The proper way to fix it would be to use the built in parameters -> http://jsfiddle.net/3PX4P/1/

Comment: I rather like http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/3PX4P/2/, personally. No, don’t actually do that. ;)

Comment: I find `this` more readable than `v`. Especially more than having to use `k,v` or `key,value`, or `index, item`, or whatever else people seem to come up with inside of their `each` iterations.

Comment: `this`, perhaps, but `""+this`? =(

Comment: @minitech - I was not very pleased with the cast either but it does not affect readability. Can you think of a faster way to cast the string aside from `''+this`?

Comment: @TravisJ: I don’t mind “faster” (the answer to that is probably to use `index, item`) but it does kind of make me go “why is that there?” — as you can see =)

Answer (score 0):

Hide the array ??. 
I suppose you mean. How to hide element, by putting their id inside an array with jquery

you could do this.

```
array = ['#id_tiempo_inicio_0', '#id_tiempo_fin_0', '#id_evento']

$.each(array,function(i, v){
   $(v).hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This will do the trick,

html

```
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<div id="three">Three</div>
<button id="button">Hide</button>
```

javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var mrHide = ['#one', "#two", "#three"];
    jQuery("button#button").click(function() {
        jQuery.each(mrHide, function(index, value) {
            jQuery(value).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maxja/LUf4y/2/